# How to add timestamp and file info in Robot Framework using LOG TO CONSOLE

Tags: python, logging, formatting, format, robotframework

The Python `logger` library has the option of logging timestamps and file information in log file/console using the `Formatter` class as below:

```
import logging
logformatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)- %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
streamlogger = logging.getLogger()
streamlogger.setLevel('DEBUG')
consolelogger = logging.StreamHandler()
consolelogger.setFormatter(logformatter)
consolelogger.setLevel('DEBUG')
streamlogger.addHandler(consolelogger)
streamlogger.debug('ZiZi')
```

and the output would look like this this:

```
2017-01-19 16:06:15,381 (testlogger.py:19)- DEBUG - ZiZi
```

In `Robot Framework`, the keyword `LOG` is used to log into report file and/or console. There is also a `LOG TO CONSOLE` keyword which only prints out given message into console. But none of these two keywords have an API for deploying what `Formatter` performs in Python's `logging` library.

Is there any trick to embed this functionality into `Robot Framework`? Are there any other `Robot Framework` keywords/libraries which I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3):

In my mind there are two ways you can achieve this kind of logging. Both of them would generate a new file, in your desired format.

The first one is to use the [Robot Listener functionality](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface). This is a set of [predefined events](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-version-2) that you can create a class for. Log Message and Message being two of particular interest to you.

The other one is a recently released project [Robot Background logger](https://github.com/robotframework/robotbackgroundlogger) that extends the standard logger class of Robotframework. This should provide some control over the formatting of the message.